# Не работает @media для определения размера экрана

Tags: media-queries, php, css, javascript

Нужно, чтобы [[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) после определения размера экрана переопределил значения для следующих атрибутов в классах, которые уже есть в этом файле css.
Коды:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1366) {
.bg_fon {width: 3000px;}
.bg_clearfon {width: 100%;}
}

.bg_fon{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 450px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 215px;
    background: url(/images/city.png);
}

.bg_clearfon{
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 389px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 215px;
    background: url(/images/city-back.png);
```

Если это важно, то перед этим определяется тип браузера в index.php следующим кодом:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/<?php
$nav = ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ) ? strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) : '';
// для браузера Mozila FireFox
if (stristr($nav, "firefox"))
{
echo "firefox.css";
}

// для браузера Chrome

elseif (stristr($nav, "chrome"))
{
echo "chrome.css";
}
?> />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишите [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) не до, а после основных стилей.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно писать так (не хватает px у max-width):

```
@media all and (max-width: 1366px) { 
    .bg_fon {width: 3000px;} 
    .bg_clearfon {width: 100%;} 
}
```

Comment: MasterAlex, Поменял с вашими исправлениями - ничего не изменилось